# Set default number of mod_wsgi processes

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, process, mod-wsgi

I have a virtual host setup with the follow config directive.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject processes=2 threads=25
```

I would like to set the number of processes for each vhost using mod_wsgi to 2 without having to set it in each virtual host. How do I change the default? I would also like the ability to override this default within the vhost.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The mod_wsgi module does not provide a way of overriding the defaults. You may want to look at mod_macro:

http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/mod_macro/

as a way of defining boilerplate which can then be used multiple times in different virtual hosts.